# ORA-12154 :TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Tags: oracle-11g, iis-8.5

I have recently migrated one of our web site from Windows Server 2003 IIS 6.0 to Windows Server 2012 R2 IIS 8.5. The site utilises an Oracle DB via an Oracle 11g ODBC driver. An ODBC connection using the driver has been specified.

The issue is however is that after a period of time we start to receive the error from the web site:

> TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified ERROR [IM006]
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed

If I reboot the server it works for a period of time (about a day or two) and then we start to receive the error again.

The version of the driver is the same between the Windows Server 2003 and 2012 R2 servers. Strangely when we are receiving the error I am able to test the connection fine via the ODBC Data Source Administrator as well as perform a successful tnsping.

Based on the fact that it works after a reboot it leads me to think that the issue is related to a stale connection or something. Running a Wireshark and netstat is showing no attempt to even access the Oracle DB while the error is occurring.

I've read other posts of people receiving the same error however theirs doesn't seem to be an intermittent issue.
Any help would be appreciated.